# Unresponsive system with powersave governor on Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: cpu, intel, thinkpad, cpu-frequency

Using a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2018 (6th Gen) on Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel 4.18 I notice that the system feels unresponsive even in AC mode.

It's most noticable in Firefox (but not restricted to it) where text input, auto complete and hover effects have a small lag. I can use the 'performance' governor and the lag goes away, but that's just in exchange for the fan running almost constantly.

It seems to me that theres a latency when switching CPU frequencies. Additionally, I noticed that `cpupower` can't display the transition latency nor the current CPU frequency through a hardware call.

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.00 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 1.20 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency 
0
```

I'm running tlp with its [default configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linrunner/TLP/master/default). Nonetheless, here's the output of `tlp-stat -p`:

```
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Processor
CPU model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors = performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   400000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  4000000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference = balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences = default performance balance_performance balance_power power 

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      =  30 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          =   0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct         =  60 [%]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates       =  37

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu4                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu4                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu4                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu5                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu5                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu5                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu6                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu6                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu6                            = HWP_CAP: low
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu7                            = performance 
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu7                            = HWP_REQ: min
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu7                            = HWP_CAP: low

/sys/module/workqueue/parameters/power_efficient       = Y
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.
```

The firmware installed is up-to-date and includes the latest fan and thermal fixes:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | less
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: N23ET59W (1.34 )
    Release Date: 11/08/2018
    Address: 0xE0000
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Skylake CPU, the i5 6200U to be specific, and suffer from the exact same symptoms that you describe. After several hours of fiddling with bleeding edge kernels, GPU drivers, etc. I found that passing intel_pstate=no_hwp as a kernel parameter resolves the issue for me.

I stumbled upon your topic in an attempt to figure out whether more people are experiencing this, or if it's just my unit.